# Positioning in list tile drawer flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this drawer in a flutter app. The List Tile has a leading, title and a trailing. I used an icon button in  the leading in the first tile as opposed to using asset image in other tiles, so the alignment got a little distorted. How can I make it align with rest of the tiles. This is the code of the first tile:

```
 SizedBox(
                          height: 40,
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_none_sharp,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            title: Transform.translate(
                                offset: const Offset(-14, 0),
                                child: const Text('Notifications',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white))),
                            trailing: SizedBox(
                                
                        ),
```

other list tiles code :

```
SizedBox(
                          height: 40,
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                              width: 20,
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/sideMenu/Group.png',
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Transform.translate(
                              offset: const Offset(-14, 0),
                              child: const Text(
                                'Grid',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => const BlurGrid()));
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
```

I just want the notification icon to align with other leading asset images:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace the `IconButton` with an `Icon` wrapped in a `GestureDetector` and then add padding if required

```dart
SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        child: ListTile(
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {} ,
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.notifications_none_sharp,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          title: Transform.translate(
              offset: const Offset(-14, 0),
              child: const Text('Notifications',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white))),
          trailing: SizedBox(),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

that caused by IconButton.

if you want to keep use the IconButton, then you have to remove the padding and  reset the constrain.

```
ListTile(
  leading: IconButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  icon: Icon(Icons.abc),
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,    // remove the padding
  constraints: BoxConstraints(), // reset the constarins
), 
 title: Text("abcdef"),),
```

[image: result compare]

Comment: actually `ListTile` provide `onTap`  property.
you better use that property since it give splash effect for `ListTile` widget. i think its better for user experience compare between assign onTap only on the Icon.

Comment: and if you use `GestureDetector` you will not get the splash effect when the widget get tap or pressed.